# Wierd section defined not rendered exception

Tags: asp.net

I have two layouts, one is the shared layout and the other one is inhereted layout. in my inhereted layout i got a section defined

```
@section DescriptionMeta{
    <meta name="description" content="some content" />
}
```

in my base layout

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("DescriptionMeta"))
{
    RenderSection("DescriptionMeta", true); //Break point on this line then it works
}
else
{
    //default meta
}
```

everytime i run it i get - The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "DescriptionMeta".

Here is the interesting part. I put a break point on `RenderSection("DescriptionMeta", true);` and i step through (F10) it, then it works! if i get rid of the break point then i get that exception. I have tried clean rebuild reopen VS and its not helping. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright..figured out the problem. I should do @RenderSection instead of RenderSection. Don't know why the break point made it work though

Comment: You got to be kidding me, I struggled the entire day trying to figure out why this happens and figured out that if you break on it, it works. Thanks so much for this +1